# Update flask without refresh

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, python-requests

This is my java script for connecting flask using ajax but it is showing 404 error.I don't understand where I am getting wrong

```
  <script>
    function getBotResponse() {
      var rawText = $("#textInput").val();
      var userHtml = '<p class="userText"><span>' + rawText + '</span></p>';
      $("#textInput").val("");
      $("#chatbox").append(userHtml);
      document.getElementById('userInput').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/predicton',
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }).done(function(data) {
        var botHtml = '<p class="botText"><span>' + data + '</span></p>';
        $("#chatbox").append(botHtml);
        document.getElementById('userInput').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
      });
    }
    $("#textInput").keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            getBotResponse();
        }
    });
    $("#buttonInput").click(function() {
      getBotResponse();
    })

  </script>
```

The flask script to connecting above java script.I am not able to connect use the flask json result into java script.It is not able to connect,I guess problem with fetching of data from flask

```
# webapp
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/prediction', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def prediction():
    if request.form != None and 'message' in request.form:
        msg = request.form['message']
        response =  pred(str(msg))
        return jsonify(response)
    else: # Through chatbot
        #msg = request.args.get(['message'])
        response =  pred(str(request.get_json['message']))
        return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Comment: whats the error or exception you receive

Comment: Actually I am greeting 404-error but when I use <form='/prediction', method ='post' >, I am getting correct result but it refresh page, which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo error in your script :

```
url: '/predicton'
```

must be

```
url: '/prediction'
```

(In the JS implementation)

Comment: I have rectified and try to run and it is showing TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'